# What's the difference between training with Huggingface's Trainer class and native PyTorch or Tensorfllow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I came across [this](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/3?fw=pt#picking-a-pretrained-model-for-masked-language-modeling) article from Huggingface, it shows training using the Trainer API and also using a native PyTorch training loop, it talks about it as it were interchangable. But I haven't seen any explanations comparing between the two. Is it the same? Is one faster than the other? Some other third party tutorials also use the two interchangebly

Answer (score 2):

PyTorch and Lightning will give you more flexibility, whereas HuggingFace simplifies some steps to make it quicker to implement. I haven't tested the speed of both but I don't think there is a big difference.

HF also offers advantages if you plan on doing NLP tasks as they already integrate many tools (models, evaluation, datasets) in their ecosystem.

Have a look at [this](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/training), it's the official HF tutorial on fine-tuning models based on different frameworks (HF, PyTorch, TF). I would still be interested to know if someone did a comparison of speed :)